# Karma with Typescript - can't get proxy to serve my file (or I can't find it)

Tags: unit-testing, typescript, karma-jasmine

### Update

> This works when I put my **KioskTemplates.html** at the root of my testing folder.  Is there no way to do with a relative path? Or do I need to make my "basePath" be the lowest path in the karma.conf file?

## So at the moment here is what I am trying to do:

1. I have a Typescript module that I am trying to test with Karma/Jasmine
2. This module has a class with a method called **renderUI**
3. This method does a jQuery $.get method to get a Mustache template from an HTML file
4. I want to test this with Karma/Jasmine
5. I am including the file in the karma.conf.js with "included:false, serve:true"
6. I am then trying to proxy it at "/KioskTemplates.html" so that my $.get request will work

## Problems

1. My test keeps erroring with a

> WARN [web-server] : 404: /base/KioskTemplates.html

2. I've tried this with an absolute path to the include file but then I can't find it on the web server.

### Does anyone have any advice/help?

### Code

Here is the renderUI method

```
        public renderUI() {


        var visitReasonData = this.setupVisitReasonData()


        var thePromise:Observable<any> = new Observable(observer => {
            $.get('KioskTemplates.html', templates => {  
                let theTemplate = $(templates).filter('#tmpVisitReasons').html();
                let html = Mustache.to_html(theTemplate, visitReasonData);
                $('#tblVisitReasons').html(html);



                applyFontSize('.Panels', this.page);
                changeColorsFromArray([
                    '.fa-circle-thin','.fa-check','.fa-square-o','.fa-check-square-o','.fa-arrow-circle-o-right','.fa-arrow-circle-o-left','.fa-text-height'],
                    '.formbutt',
                    'background-color'
                )
                window.scrollTo(0, 0);

            }).done(() => { observer.next(true) })

        })

        return thePromise
    }
```

Here is my karma.conf.js

```
    module.exports = function(config) {
      config.set({

        // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
        basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine','karma-typescript','fixture'],

    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      '../secrets.ts',
      'tests/*.ts',
      "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/**/*.css",
      "../../../../Websites/VirtualOneStop/Vos/vosnet/JavaScript/StaffEfficiency/source/*.ts",
      "../../../../Websites/VirtualOneStop/Vos/vosnet/JavaScript/StaffEfficiency/entry-points/*.ts",
      "tests/**/*.json", 
      { pattern: '../../../../Websites/VirtualOneStop/Vos/vosnet/OneStopEfficiency/KioskTemplates.html', included:true, served:true }
    ],

    proxies : {
      '/KioskTemplates.html':'/base/KioskTemplates.html'
    },


    karmaTypescriptConfig: {
      compilerOptions: {
        allowJs:true,
        module: "commonjs",
        target:"es5",
        noImplicitAny: false,
        removeComments: true,
        preserveConstEnums: true,
        sourceMap: true
      },
      include: [
        "../../../../Websites/VirtualOneStop/Vos/vosnet/JavaScript/StaffEfficiency/source/*.ts",
        "../../../../Websites/VirtualOneStop/Vos/vosnet/JavaScript/StaffEfficiency/entry-points/*.ts",
        "tests/*.ts",
        '../secrets.ts',
        "../typings.d.ts",
        "tests/**/*.json"
    ],
    exclude: [
      "../../../../Websites/VirtualOneStop/Vos/vosnet/JavaScript/StaffEfficiency/node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts",
      "../../../../Websites/VirtualOneStop/Vos/vosnet/JavaScript/StaffEfficiency/source/KioskScanning.ts",
      "../node_modules",
      "../node_modules/@types/**/*.ts"

  ]
    },


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
      "../../../../Websites/VirtualOneStop/Vos/vosnet/JavaScript/StaffEfficiency/source/*.ts":['karma-typescript'],
      "../../../../Websites/VirtualOneStop/Vos/vosnet/JavaScript/StaffEfficiency/entry-points/*.ts":['karma-typescript'],
      'tests/*.ts':['karma-typescript'],
      '../secrets.ts':['karma-typescript'],
      'tests/**/*.json': ['json_fixtures']
    },

    //plugins: ['karma-browserify'],


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['dots'],

    jsonFixturesPreprocessor: {
      variableName: '__json__'
    },


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['Chrome'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false,

    // Concurrency level
    // how many browser should be started simultaneous
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
}
```

The error

```
Chrome 60.0.3112 (Windows 7 0.0.0): Executed 218 of 218 (1 FAILED) (6.172 secs / 5.603 secs)
21 09 2017 11:23:10.577:INFO [compiler.karma-typescript]: Compiling project using Typescript 2.5.2
21 09 2017 11:23:11.282:ERROR [compiler.karma-typescript]: node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(2957,63): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Iterable'.

21 09 2017 11:23:11.282:ERROR [compiler.karma-typescript]: ../../../Websites/VirtualOneStop/Vos/vosnet/JavaScript/StaffEfficiency/node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(58,60): err
or TS2693: 'Promise' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

21 09 2017 11:23:11.527:INFO [compiler.karma-typescript]: Compiled 17 files in 942 ms.
21 09 2017 11:23:12.166:INFO [bundler.karma-typescript]: Bundled imports for 1 file(s) in 138 ms.
21 09 2017 11:23:12.326:INFO [watcher]: Changed file "C:/[hidden]/[hidden]/[hidden]/[hidden]/[hidden]/[hidden]/Source/Websites/VirtualOneStop/Vos/vosnet/JavaScript/Sta
ffEfficiency/source/KioskVisitReason.ts".
21 09 2017 11:23:12.340:INFO [watcher]: Changed file "C:/Users/[hidden]/[hidden]/[hidden]/Temp/karma-typescript-bundle-23924qLtCs3Pz64A0.js".
21 09 2017 11:23:12.848:WARN [web-server]: 404: /absoluteC:/[hidden]/[hidden]/[hidden]/[hidden]/[hidden]/[hidden]/Source/Testing/JavascriptUnitTests/StaffEfficiency/no
de_modules/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0
21 09 2017 11:23:12.856:WARN [web-server]: 404: /absoluteC:/[hidden]/[hidden]/[hidden]/[hidden]/[hidden]/[hidden]/Source/Testing/JavascriptUnitTests/StaffEfficiency/no
de_modules/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.7.0
........21 09 2017 11:23:13.021:WARN [web-server]: 404: /absoluteC:/[hidden]/[hidden]/[hidden]/[hidden]/[hidden]/[hidden]/Source/Testing/JavascriptUnitTests/StaffEffic
iency/node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.7.0
........................................................................
................................................................................
......................................................21 09 2017 11:23:14.026:WARN [web-server]: 404: /base/KioskTemplates.html

LOG: true
...
LOG: 0
.
Chrome 60.0.3112 (Windows 7 0.0.0): Executed 218 of 218 SUCCESS (1.241 secs / 0.62 secs)
```

Answer (score 1):

So I figured this out after all.

My problem was that the `basePath` value needed to ***truly*** be the base.

So instead of doing this

```
config.set({
        // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
        basePath: '',

    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine', 'karma-typescript'],

    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      { pattern: "../../../../Websites/VirtualOneStop/Vos/vosnet/OneStopEfficiency/KioskTemplates.html", included: false, served: true, nocache: true },
      { pattern:"../../../../Websites/VirtualOneStop/Vos/vosnet/JavaScript/StaffEfficiency/source/**/*.ts"},
      { pattern:"../../../../Testing/JavascriptUnitTests/StaffEfficiency/VOSGreeter/KioskVisitReasonsTest.ts"},
    ],

    proxies: {
      "/KioskTemplates.html": "/base/KioskTemplates.html"},
```

I'm now doing this

```
 config.set({

        // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
        basePath: '../../../../../Source',

    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine', 'karma-typescript'],

    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      { pattern: "Websites/VirtualOneStop/Vos/vosnet/OneStopEfficiency/KioskTemplates.html", included: false, served: true, nocache: true },
      { pattern:"Websites/VirtualOneStop/Vos/vosnet/JavaScript/StaffEfficiency/source/**/*.ts"},
      { pattern:"Testing/JavascriptUnitTests/StaffEfficiency/VOSGreeter/KioskVisitReasonsTest.ts"},
    ],

    proxies: {
      "/KioskTemplates.html": "/base/Websites/VirtualOneStop/Vos/vosnet/OneStopEfficiency/KioskTemplates.html"},
```